# How to rename colab My Drive folder to other name?

Tags: linux, rename, google-colaboratory

I'm using colab and I need to rename colab My Drive folder.

I'm using the following command:

```
!mv /content/gdrive/My\ Drive /content/gdrive/MyDrive
```

But is giving me the following error:

```
mv: cannot move '/content/gdrive/My Drive' to a subdirectory of itself, '/content/gdrive/MyDrive'
```

How can I do it?

Comment: Google colab linux command line isn't a programming and development question?

Comment: This seems to be a question on commands that don't have anything to do with programming and development. There are more appropriate sites for the question.

Comment: Ok, can you help me solve my problem?

Comment: Delete here and repost to https://superuser.com ? Please read [Help On-topic](https://stackoverflow.com/Help/On-topic) before posting more Qs here. Good luck.

Comment: did you ever find a solution?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try
!ln -s /content/drive/My\ Drive/ mydrive